# ¿Como puedo hacer un salto de linea en el text de una Label en XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, salto-de-linea, maui

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicacion con .NET MAUI que utiliza C# para el behind y XAML para la interfaz de usuario, ahora bien, me he visto que al momento de escribir el texto de una label desde el XAML no encuentro forma de hacer un salto de linea, por lo que la unica forma que he encontrado es hacerlo desde C# creando una string y asignandola a la propiedad text de dicha label.

Muestro aqui el codigo que he tenido que usar en **C#** para poder realizar el salto de linea:

```csharp
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string cardsCollectorDescription = "CardsCollector es una aplicacion creada para practicar algunas bases de programacion en .NET MAUI\n\nPor lo que no es recomendable tomarla enserio.";

            description.Text = cardsCollectorDescription;
        }
```

Muestro aqui como me gustaria hacerlo en ***XAML*** para ahorrar codigo:

```
<Label Text="CardsCollector es una aplicacion creada para practicar algunas bases de programacion en .NET MAUI\n\nPor lo que no es recomendable tomarla enserio."
```

Este es el concepto ya que en XAML no puedes usar `\n` , o al menos yo no he encontrado la forma, por lo que me gustaria saber si alguien sabe de algun concepto similar para evitar un poco de codigo en C#.

Espero haber formulado la pregunta correctamente y muchas gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `&#x0a;`

Ejemplo

```
<Label Text="CardsCollector es una aplicacion creada para practicar algunas bases de programacion en .NET MAUI&#x0a;&#x0a;Por lo que no es recomendable tomarla enserio."/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Increible llevaba mucho rato buscando y no encontraba nada muchisimas gracias de verdad